# Google Maps Fragment Integration

Tags: android

Good day!

I have a class that extends **SupportMapFragment** and implement **OnMapReadyCallback**. This fragment load map normally with no layout file. But i need additional functionality - zoom controls. Can i use just this code, or i have to crate special layout.xml for this fragment?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getMapAsync(this);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        UiSettings settings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
        settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
```